# Change to .travel domain when "traveling" is part of business name?

Tags: domains

I have a business called [Easter Island Traveling](http://www.easterislandtraveling.com). The current URL is [www.easterislandtraveling.com](http://www.easterislandtraveling.com). Would it be a good idea to buy the domain www.easterisland.travel?

Personally I really like the idea of dramatically shortening the URL this way. I like how the .travel URL looks.

I guess my real question is: are .travel domains taken seriously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are still relatively new so there is not much in favour or against, so if you want to get that domain, just go for it.

But since you already have an existing web site, you have to consider what do you want to do with it, if you want to keep both sites and be reached with both URls, it's OK, just remember to set the respective redirections. If, on the other hand, you want to relinquish the original one, don't do it soon, first set redirections from the original one and have a transition process.

Comment: +1. Same as with all new TLDs it takes time until they are more widely adopted and used.

Comment: @edvinas.me You gotta vote up for +1 haha. I'll do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, PatomaS. I would definitely keep the original domain until the end of time, adding a 301 redirect.

@edvinas.me so you think .travel is a domain that's here to stay? I noticed that Chile uses chile.travel as their official travel site.

What do you guys think yourselves, your personal opinions? Do .travel domains give a professional impression, or do you feel it's on the contrary?

Comment: I think that right now there is less poor use of catchy domains, which translates in an overall minimum quality. So far, .travel seems good and the sooner that people start using it with proper sites an legal content, the better. Of course there will be scams someday with fishy sites, but hopefully it won't be common.

Comment: Thanks for your comment PatomaS, I appreciate it! It seems I'll be one of those that adds some credit to the .travel domain then, being a serious business using it! That is, if I'm successful in getting it.